# Compare size of two files from separated directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am comparing files from two separated directories. Right now I would like to check if two files has same size. I am using nested loops and condition, but there is a problem with it. The condition is not working, my editor not coloring properly the: %%~zj.
Source code of my batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
    if not exist %1%%i goto no
    for %%j in ("%1*") do (
        echo first %%~zi
        echo second %%~zj
        if %%~zi not %%~zj goto rem here I want to break the loop
    )
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That is not the proper syntax for the `IF` command. Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?`.  But the short answer is: `IF NOT %%~zi==%%~zj goto....`

Answer (score 1):

Use NEQ instead of not for comparison, i.e.

```
if %%~zi NEQ %%~zj
```

Comment: That is right, I copied code with "not" instead of "neq", but the problem still exists. With that form, I can not compare size of two files from different folders, I am comparing only files from the same folder.\

Comment: So is %1 the other folder?  Do you just need to change it to %1\%%i?